# /usr/local/bin/gunicorn Exec format error Apple M1 Chip

Tags: python, docker, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, gunicorn

I'm using gke engine to run the docker image. Whenever I'm pushing the container it says exec /usr/local/bin/gunicorn exec format error. I can see this error inside the pod log.

Using macbook m1 pro chip

Here is my Docker file:

```
FROM python:3.7
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN ls -la ./
EXPOSE 80
ENTRYPOINT ["gunicorn", "-w", "2", "-b", ":80", "main:app", "--timeout", "300"]
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: Did you copy over an M1 binary into an x86_64 container?

Comment: How can I see a container architecture?

Comment: `docker inspect` but it should also match your system ISA unless you're specifically building for another architecture. Remember, you generally can't copy binaries over, you'll need to build any compiled extensions, tools or apps in the target container.

Comment: What should be my next move??

Comment: Where does `gunicorn` come from? What architecture are you building for?

Answer (score 1):

change the base image to be compatible with platform change to below if for a linux or add any related platform

```
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 python:3.7
```

This worked for me in AWS, for other ways to handle visit [this](https://pythonspeed.com/articles/docker-build-problems-mac/)

Answer (score 0):

“exec format” error means the architecture of the Docker image and your host system does not match.
You must use container images that are compatible with the architecture of the node where you intend to run the workloads

Check this [documentation on building multi-arch images on GKE](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/build-multi-arch-for-arm#what_is_a_multi-arch_image)

Comment: if i command  ls -l /usr/local/bin/gunicorn into the mac terminal- it says
ls: /usr/local/bin/gunicorn: No such file or directory

If I command which gunicorn it says
/Users/taposhkumar/Desktop/project/Manpower_dev/planner/venv_dev/bin/gunicorn

Is't it gunicorn file is missing from usr/local/bin??How can I get it there to make it compatible? @Siegfred V.